# Drag and Drop to upload files not uploading files larger than about 200KB

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, drag-and-drop, filesize

So I made a drag and drop that uploads file(s) into a mysql database and a separate uploads folder located on the server using ajax. It works like a charm until I get to about 200KB.
I just graduated last year, so it is possible that I am missing something simple.
I have posted both uploadr.php and the js fuction where the drag and drop is located below.

(ignore the mysql_query, I know that is the old way of doing things, but I am on an older website)

uploadr.php

```
<?php
include '../db.php';
include '../functions.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

session_start();
$link=mysql_connect($hostname,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
mysql_select_db($_SESSION["databasename"]);
$authenticated=false;
$authenticated=authenticateuser($link,$_SESSION["username"],$_SESSION["password"]);
if($authenticated>0 AND $authenticated<=2){
}else{
  header("location: ../noaccess.php");
  exit;
}

ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", __DIR__ . "/log/php-error.log");

if(isset($_FILES['images'])) {
    for($count = 0; $count < count($_FILES['images']['name']); $count++) {
        //$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['images']['name'][$count], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        //$new_name = uniqid().$_FILES['images']['name'][$count];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$count], '/web/websitename/html/chase/uploads/'.$_SESSION["databasename"].'/sys/' . $_FILES['images']['name'][$count]);
    

        $q='INSERT INTO uploads SET
              filename="'.$_FILES['images']['name'][$count].'",
              filesize="'.$_FILES['images']['size'][$count].'",
              depoid="1",
              uploadtime="'.time().'"';
              
        mysql_query($q);
    
    }
    echo 'success';
}

?>
```

this is where the drag and drop is located

```
_('drag_drop').ondrop = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_data  = new FormData();
    var image_number = 1;
    var error = '';
    var drop_files = event.dataTransfer.files;
    for(var count = 0; count < drop_files.length; count++) {
    
        extension = drop_files[count].name.split('.').pop();
        if(extension=='csv' || extension=='jpg' || extension=='jpeg' || extension=='gif' || extension=='mp3' || extension=='mp4' || extension=='m4a' ||
                extension=='wma' || extension=='wmv' || extension=='pm' || extension=='png' || extension=='bmp' || extension=='tif' || extension=='pdf' || 
                extension=='txt' || extension=='doc' || extension=='dix' || extension=='docx' || extension=='dot' || extension=='msg' || extension=='rtf' || 
                extension=='pst' || extension=='pfx' || extension=='ptx' || extension=='ptf' || extension=='ptz' || extension=='eml' || extension=='ecl' || 
                extension=='mdi' || extension=='wav' || extension=='wpd' || extension=='dm' || extension=='sgnl' || extension=='trn' || extension=='xls' || 
                extension=='xlsx' || extension=='ytg' || extension=='zip' || extension=='bkc' || extension=='lef' || extension=='sgpgl' || extension=='sgngl' || 
                extension=='xmef' || extension=='not' || extension=='pages' || extension=='numbers' || extension=='key' || extension=='prproj' || extension=='pk' || 
                extension=='pek' || extension=='cfa' || extension=='pkf' || extension=='dts' || extension=='mxf' || extension=='lrt' || extension=='aml' || 
                extension=='dvt' || extension=='cms' || extension=='oll' || extension=='mdb' || extension=='sbf' || extension=='vid' || extension=='exh' || 
                extension=='pts' || extension=='dil' || extension=='mpg' || extension=='prn' || extension=='pptx' || extension=='vcf' || extension=='ics' || 
                extension=='mov' || extension=='avi' || extension=='scc' || extension=='srt'){
                
            form_data.append("images[]", drop_files[count]);
        }
        else {
            error += '<div class="alert alert-danger"><b>'+image_number+'</b> Selected File must be .jpg or .png Only.</div>';
        }
        image_number++;
    }

    if(error != '') {
        _('uploaded_image').innerHTML = error;
        _('drag_drop').style.borderColor = '#ccc';
        document.location='searchz.php?uploaded=2';
    }
    else {
        _('progress_bar').style.display = 'block';
        var ajax_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax_request.open("POST", "uploadr.php",true);
        ajax_request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(event){
            var percent_completed = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);
            _('progress_bar_process').style.width = percent_completed + '%';
            _('progress_bar_process').innerHTML = percent_completed + '% completed';
        });
        ajax_request.addEventListener('load', function(event){
            _('uploaded_image').innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-success">Files Uploaded Successfully</div>';
            _('drag_drop').style.borderColor = '#ccc';
        });
        document.location='searchz.php?uploaded=1';
        ajax_request.send(form_data);
    }
}
```

I have checked my htaccess file and my upload_max_filesize, post_max_size, and memory_limit are all set well above what I am trying to do. The default upload size is 2MB anyway which is far larger than I am able to upload.  Y'all take a look and let me know what y'all think.

note currently this does not check if the upload succeeds or not. It just checks the extension and if it is an allowed extension, then it assumes that it will succeed. I haven't learned how to hear back from an ajax request since this is my first time working with ajax. I wanted to get this to work first

Comment: `$_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$ebcount]` what is `$ebcount` Does this really work for small files?

Comment: this should just be count, probably a mistake when I pasted it over and changed the name of the website.

Comment: NOTE `upload_max_filesize` has to cover ALL the files you are uploding, so if you are uploading multiple files the total size of all the files has to be less than `upload_max_filesize`

Comment: I edited the post so that it shows $count. the code never had 'ebcount' in it. that was a typo when making the post.

Comment: Yes, upload_max_filesize and post_max_size are both 50MB, this was the first thing that I considered to be the problem after looking online, but 50MB is a whole lot more than I'm failing at @RiggsFolly